# Connecting from Windows 7 to MySQL docker container on VirtualBox CentOs

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, virtualbox

I have Windows 7 on my laptop and used VirtualBox for install CentOs on it.
I have installed docker on CentOS and started MySQL server using:

```
sudo docker run -name mysql -p 3306:3306
```

I can see that mysql container is up and running on VM but I am unable to connect to it from Windows using MySQL workbench. Is there a possibility to do so?
edit:
I have configured two adapters: first one is NAT and second one is a VirtualBox Host Only Network so I am able to connect to VB and have internet access. I am using 192.168.56.101 to connect to VB and it is successful. I can easily ping and connect to CentOS using ssh. The issue is how to setup MySQL using docker so I will be able to connect to it from Windows? Should I use 127.0.0.0 and port 3306 or should I perform some routing or port forwarding?

Comment: Yes, but you didn't tell us how you configured the network in virtualbox.

Comment: edited post and added it to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved an issue. It seems like I could not connect because of MySQL changing their authentication style somewhere in releases 8.0

I have tried with an earlier version 5.7 as:

```
sudo docker run --name testdb-mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -e MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb -d mysql:5.7
```

I have used 192.168.56.101:3306 address with root user and admin password in MySQL Workbench and it worked as intended. No routing needed.